# For $a,b>0$ and $c\ge0$ prove that $\frac{2(a+b)}{3a+6b+9c}+\frac{6(b+c)}{5a+2b+3c}+\frac{3(a+c)}{2a+8b+6c}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, problem-solving, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For $a,b>0$ and $c\ge0$ prove that $\frac{2(a+b)}{3a+6b+9c}+\frac{6(b+c)}{5a+2b+3c}+\frac{3(a+c)}{2a+8b+6c}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

This question is easily solved if you say: $x=3a+6b+9c$, $y=5a+2b+3c$, $z=2a+8b+6c$.

From this we have that:

$2(a+b)=\frac{-x+y+z}{2}$

$6(b+c)=\frac{x-y+z}{2}$

$3(c+a)=\frac{x+y-z}{2}$

Hence it is enough to prove that $\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{x}{z}+\frac{y}{z}\ge6$ which holds true.

I couldn't solve this question, as I couldn't think of the substitution. Could you please explain to me intuitively why I should have thought of doing the particular $x,y,z$ substitutions?

Comment: I guess the point is that the numerators are `simple' linear combinations of the denominators? So picking the three denominators as your variables looks like a good idea.

Comment: This is called Ravi-substitution https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution/

Comment: @ErikSatie Not quite. The Ravi-substitution is applied when the variables are side lengths of triangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not too the intuitive for me. The more intuitive substituion for me is

$$
\begin{align}
x&=2(a+b)\\
y&=6(b+c)\\
z&=3(a+c)
\end{align}
$$

which will give us

$$
\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}\geq\frac{3}{2}
$$

which is a well known inequality

Comment: Nesbitt's inequality hidden nice ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901012/nesbitt-inequality-symmetric-proof

Comment: Funny how I just found another way to prove Nesbitt:

$y+z=r, z+x=s, x+y=t$, then 

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{y+z} = \sum_{cyc} \left( \frac{s+t}{2r} - \frac 12 \right) = \frac 12 \sum_{cyc} \frac{s+t}{r} - \frac 32 \ge \frac 12 \times 6 - \frac 32=\frac 32$$