# Nesbitt's Inequality $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a book which focus in inequality.

I'm stuck in this question. Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. ([Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality)) Prove the inequality $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

So the first step of solution given is $\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}+\frac{a+c}{c+b}+\frac{c+b}{a+c}+\frac{b+a}{a+c}+\frac{a+c}{b+a}\geq2+2+2=6$

I don't know how to proceed from the question to the first step of solution. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The last term on the LHS of the inequality should be $\frac{a+c}{b+a}$

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980751/proof-of-nesbitts-inequality?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step of the solution says that $X+\frac1X+Y+\frac1Y+Z+\frac1Z\geq2+2+2$.
where $X=\frac{a+b}{b+c}$ and so on.
Do you know that $X+\frac1X$ is always $2$ or more whenever $X>0$?

Comment: I've understood. Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why $X+\frac{1}{X}$ is always greater and equal to 2?

Comment: If you believe the AM-GM inequality, then it follows from the fact that the geometric mean of $X$ and $1/X$ is $1$, so the arithmetic mean is at least $1$.

Comment: @Mathxx
if $\; X \ge 1\;$ then $\frac{1}{X}+X =\frac{X^2+X}{X} \ge \frac{X+X}{X} \ge 2\;$ If $X \le 1\;$then $X\;$can be written as $X=\frac{1}{Y}\;$ where $\; Y \ge 1 \;$. Hence, $\; \frac{1}{X}+X=\frac{1}{Y}+Y \ge 2$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: set 
$$b+c=x$$
$$c+a=y$$
$$a+b=z$$
adding we get
$$a+b+c=\frac{x+y+z}{2}$$ and we can compute $$a+x=\frac{x+y+z}{2}$$ thus $$a=\frac{-x+y+z}{2}$$ etc

Answer (score 1):

We have three expressions:
$$S=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}$$

$$M=\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}+\frac{a}{a+b}$$

$$N=\frac{c}{b+c}+\frac{a}{c+a}+\frac{b}{a+b}$$
Obviously, we have $M+N=3$ According to AM-GM,we have:

$$M+S=\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b}\geqslant 3$$
$$N+S=\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+b}{c+a}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}\geqslant 3$$
Thus, $M+N+2S\geqslant 6$ so $2S\geqslant 3$ so $S\geqslant \dfrac{3}{2}$ q.e.d

Answer (score 0):

More easier and obvious answer:
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+c}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\frac{2a}{b+c}+\frac{2c}{a+b}+\frac{2b}{a+c}\geq3$$
$$\frac{2a+b+c}{b+c}+\frac{b+2c+a}{a+b}+\frac{c+2b+a}{a+c}\geq6$$
$$\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}+\frac{a+c}{c+b}+\frac{c+b}{a+c}+\frac{b+a}{a+c}+\frac{a+c}{b+a}\geq6$$

Comment: I don't think this addresses the questioner's specific problem at all.

Comment: I started from the first step that he gave

Comment: Yes. The questioner wants to know how to get TO the first step.

Comment: In this case, just reversing is right.